# JQuery checkbox object reference

Tags: jquery, this

I have the following code (that works) to toggle an iPhone style checkbox:

```
            $('.iphone-style').live('click', function() {

                checkboxID      = '#' + $(this).attr('rel');

                if($(checkboxID)[0].checked == false) {
                    $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: '0% 100%'});

                    $(checkboxID)[0].checked = true;
                    $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');

                } else {

                    $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: '100% 0%'});

                    $(checkboxID)[0].checked = false;
                    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');

                }
              });
```

In a different function, I would like a specific checkbox (AerialView) to be unchecked when another checkbox (PhotoStyles) is unchecked. I don't know how to correctly replace the 'this' reference with something more specific. I have the following (which doesn't work):

```
                if($('#PhotoStylesCheck')[0].checked == false) {

                    $('#AerialViewCheck').animate({backgroundPosition: '100% 0%'});
                    $('#AerialViewCheck')[0].checked = false;
                    $('#AerialViewCheck').removeClass('on').addClass('off');

                }
```

Note that I confirmed that the if statement works and the setting the checked to false also works. The visual elements of 'animate', 'removeClass', and 'addClass' do not work.

Comment: Can you show some html code or create fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `id` of checkbox, then syntax for checking whether it is checked or not is :

```
if($('#' + id).is(":checked")) {
   // it is checked
}
else {
   // it is not checked
}
```

In your case you are not using the correct syntax for checking the checkbox, and also you are getting a 'true' value. OK.

Now if `$('#AerialViewCheck')[0]` is the checkbox element, then apply the animate, addClass, removeClass on this itself. Why you are trying to apply on `$('#AerialViewCheck')` ? Use like this :

```
$('#AerialViewCheck')[0].animate({backgroundPosition: '100% 0%'});
$('#AerialViewCheck')[0].removeClass('on').addClass('off');
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. I don't know if I am totally off ... but if you look in the original code (that works) the animate, removeClass and addClass functions reference the object (with the 'this' call). They don't reference the ID. I just don't know how to reference a specific object (AerialView in this case) from the ID when I can't call 'this'.